# do i understand correct: rails is translating/changeing names while creating Models, etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I wanted to create a model `person`; what I got was a mixture of `person` and `people`.
Some thing like that with `ci_data`: I got a mixture of `ci_data` and `ci_datum`.

Why? ok, the second example gave a 'warning', but the first, the person?
and why a mixture?

I think this behavior is very confusing ...

Commands and Output:

```
rails generate scaffold person name_first:string name_last:string  mail:string last_seen:time

      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140628161302_create_people.rb
      create    app/models/person.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/unit/person_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/people.yml
      invoke  resource_route
       route    resources :people
      invoke  scaffold_controller
      create    app/controllers/people_controller.rb
      invoke    erb
      create      app/views/people
      create      app/views/people/index.html.erb
      create      app/views/people/edit.html.erb
      create      app/views/people/show.html.erb
      create      app/views/people/new.html.erb
      create      app/views/people/_form.html.erb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/functional/people_controller_test.rb
      invoke    helper
      create      app/helpers/people_helper.rb
      invoke      test_unit
      create        test/unit/helpers/people_helper_test.rb
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/people.js.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/people.css.scss
      invoke  scss
      create    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss

rails generate scaffold ci_data name:string category:string description:string

Plural version of the model detected, using singularized version. Override with --force-plural.
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140628161843_create_ci_data.rb
      create    app/models/ci_datum.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/unit/ci_datum_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/ci_data.yml
      invoke  resource_route
       route    resources :ci_data
      invoke  scaffold_controller
      create    app/controllers/ci_data_controller.rb
      invoke    erb
      create      app/views/ci_data
      create      app/views/ci_data/index.html.erb
      create      app/views/ci_data/edit.html.erb
      create      app/views/ci_data/show.html.erb
      create      app/views/ci_data/new.html.erb
      create      app/views/ci_data/_form.html.erb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/functional/ci_data_controller_test.rb
      invoke    helper
      create      app/helpers/ci_data_helper.rb
      invoke      test_unit
      create        test/unit/helpers/ci_data_helper_test.rb
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/ci_data.js.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/ci_data.css.scss
      invoke  scss
   identical    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal in Rails, ActiveSupport::Inflector does care about this and you can either switch it off or define new inflections.

Inflections makes sense. When you define a model Person then class should be Person but database should be 'People' as it's full of People. It helps you organise app.

Model -> Singular (Person)
Controller and Database (Plural)

Rails does handle this automatically so when you call `create` in `PeopleController` it will call `Person` model.

Inflections can be defined as:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'clothing', 'clothes'
end
```

more examples:

```
inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1en'
inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'
inflect.irregular 'person', 'people'
inflect.uncountable %w( fish sheep )
```

After generating models with some weird names, just make sure that the migration has the name in right plural form and if it doesn't just define it as described above.

Comment: Got it! My problem was, that I started with irregular words, person/people, I didnt see it (I am not native english speaker) and data/datum hm ... Next time I try Model 'Virus' lets see ...